# Can't ping across bridge

Tags: networking, server, iptables, network-bridge

I'm fairly weak in the iptables/bridging knowledge but I followed https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge and customized it for my situation.

Here is my config(with a few removed items:

```
#auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.216.1.247
netmask 255.255.248.0
gateway 10.216.1.254

#auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 10.1.1.254
netmask 255.255.0.0

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
address 10.216.1.247
netmask 255.255.248.0
gateway 10.216.1.254
bridge_ports eth0 eth1
```

And the ifconfig
~$ ifconfig

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:5d:41:53:0e
          inet addr:10.216.1.247  Bcast:10.216.7.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:5dff:fe41:530e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:994262 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:579 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:65360679 (65.3 MB)  TX bytes:56582 (56.5 KB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:5d:41:53:0e
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:5dff:fe41:530e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:26145 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:28727 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:3331228 (3.3 MB)  TX bytes:3336348 (3.3 MB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:5d:41:53:0f
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:968896 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:25616 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:76009978 (76.0 MB)  TX bytes:3245351 (3.2 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:181 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:181 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:14024 (14.0 KB)  TX bytes:14024 (14.0 KB)
```

And my system(windows) I am trying to ping from

```
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.216.1.23(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.248.0
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.254(Duplicate)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.216.1.254
```

When I ping a known pingable address(10.1.1.160) I get all timeouts.
When the bridge is disabled I can ping both sides from the bridge machine.

Comment: In your `/etc/network/interfaces` file, delete the eth0 stuff and just have it as a bridge port. Also delete eth1 from your bridge_ports lines, as from what I see, it shouldn't be bridged. Show us your iptables rule set.

Comment: Hmm Okay, I wanted eth0 and eth1 to be bridged, I only want one to be on the bridge? I guess I don't understand that part.

Comment: We need more information to know for sure. I am only guessing.

Comment: It seems you are mixing stuff/concepts. As you can see from the tutorial you mention, you should not have the `iface eth0` and `iface eth1` if these are members of your bridge (or just with `manual` and without any IP related values). You should probably give here more details of your network setup and exactly what you want to achieve. You need to give your bridge an IP only if it needs to send/receive traffic itself, if it just merges two network you can work without.